# vocabulary about returning ones favor

Tags: phrases, vocabulary

You're asking someone to postpone something, or do something on behalf of you and at the end you want to say to him I will try to recoup it later. I will try to work on your behalf later. I'll return your favor later.

What is a casual way of saying such thing, In daily informal conversations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[I owe you (one)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/i-owe-you-one)*** is a colloquial expression:

> - (informal)  said to thank someone for helping you and as a way of saying that you will do something for them in the future:
>   *Thanks for the help, Bill - I owe you one.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: good one. thanks. do you know anything else which is less strong? I mean, I feel like 'I owe you (one)' is something you usually say to someone who's help has been significant. how about small routine things? Something in between a simple 'Thank you' and 'I owe you one'?

Comment: It is actually a way to say thanks,  to show appreciation for the favor received, it does not imply  any obligation.